# How can I display multiple rows in a DataGrid for a single row from a DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to display a single data record consisting of three columns (ID, ITEM_NUMBER, and QUANTITY) across two lines in a DataGrid. I am not sure if this is possible or not and I am only able to find instructions in suggested solutions using a DataGridView, which is not an option in my situation.

I would like to display the ID on one row and the ITEM_NUMBER and QUANTITY on a row below it, along with having headers for the columns in the same layout. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: I am working with the .Net 3.5 Compact Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping on ID field. There is not direct control provided by .Net Framework 3.5 but solutions are available. You can create user control , focus on data binding events of the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to solve is to overwrite the OnPaint method or to manipulate it.
So that you can build your own cell content.
I did it to show an image in a cell.

Otherwise I think there is no possible solution to do this.

If you searching in general for advanced controls in CF try this out:

http://www.resco.net/mobileformstoolkit/